# Blank page opened when trying to start a Selenium test on Chrome v54.0.2810.98 and Selenium webdriver 2.53.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, watir-webdriver, minitest

I am trying to Start a Selenium test in Chrome but I am only seeing a blank page.  This only started happening after updating to the version 54.0.2810.98 (64-bit) of Chrome.

This is the version of `watir-webdriver` I am using:  `0.7.0.8.`

```
OS Version:  10.11.6, El Capitan
```

My questions are:

Does my combination of watir-webdriver, selenium-webdriver work with the latest version of Chrome?

If it does, what do i need to do to get it running again?

If not, do I need to update to Selenium3?

Here is the stack trace:

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError: Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)
    /Users/nickbrill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `initialize'
    /Users/nickbrill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `open'
    /Users/nickbrill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `block in connect'
    /Users/nickbrill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:69:in `timeout'
    /Users/nickbrill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:100:in `timeout'
    /Users/nickbrill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `connect'
    /Users/nickbrill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:756:in `do_start'
    /Users/nickbrill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
    /Users/nickbrill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1285:in `request'
    /Users/nickbrill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@selenium-finance/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:107:in `response_for'
    /Users/nickbrill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@selenium-finance/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:58:in `request'
    /Users/nickbrill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@selenium-finance/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
    /Users/nickbrill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@selenium-finance/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:649:in `raw_execute'
    /Users/nickbrill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@selenium-finance/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:627:in `execute'
    /Users/nickbrill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@selenium-finance/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:238:in `getWindowHandles'
    /Users/nickbrill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@selenium-finance/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/target_locator.rb:75:in `ensure in window'
    /Users/nickbrill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@selenium-finance/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/target_locator.rb:78:in `window'
    /Users/nickbrill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@selenium-finance/gems/watir-webdriver-0.7.0.8/lib/watir-webdriver/window.rb:193:in `use'
    /Users/nickbrill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@selenium-finance/gems/watir-webdriver-0.7.0.8/lib/watir-webdriver/window.rb:96:in `maximize'
    /Users/nickbrill/sportngin/selenium-finance/test/utilities/selenium_utilities.rb:44:in `start_selenium'
    /Users/nickbrill/sportngin/selenium-finance/test/base_test.rb:12:in `setup'
/Users/nickbrill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `initialize'
/Users/nickbrill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `open'
/Users/nickbrill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `block in connect'
/Users/nickbrill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:69:in `timeout'
/Users/nickbrill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:100:in `timeout'
/Users/nickbrill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `connect'
/Users/nickbrill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:756:in `do_start'
/Users/nickbrill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
/Users/nickbrill/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1285:in `request'
/Users/nickbrill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@selenium-finance/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:107:in `response_for'
/Users/nickbrill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@selenium-finance/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:58:in `request'
/Users/nickbrill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@selenium-finance/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
/Users/nickbrill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@selenium-finance/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:649:in `raw_execute'
/Users/nickbrill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@selenium-finance/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:627:in `execute'
/Users/nickbrill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@selenium-finance/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:238:in `getWindowHandles'
/Users/nickbrill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@selenium-finance/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/target_locator.rb:75:in `ensure in window'
/Users/nickbrill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@selenium-finance/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/target_locator.rb:78:in `window'
/Users/nickbrill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@selenium-finance/gems/watir-webdriver-0.7.0.8/lib/watir-webdriver/window.rb:193:in `use'
/Users/nickbrill/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@selenium-finance/gems/watir-webdriver-0.7.0.8/lib/watir-webdriver/window.rb:96:in `maximize'
```

Comment: Have you updated your Chromedriver to one that supports Chrome v54?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Justin.  Unfortunately, updating to v2.26 of ChromeDriver didn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Running `rm -rf ~/.chromedriver-helper` solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is yes.

Like Justin suggested, the most important factor is keeping [chromedriver version](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) matched with Chrome browser version.

Beyond that, the latest of everything provides a number of benefits. watir-webdriver is deprecated in favor of Watir 6.0, which requires selenium 3, which requires updating to at least ruby 2.0, but ideally to a supported version of ruby. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply titusfortner.  Unfortunately, updating to v2.26 of ChromeDriver didn't solve my issue.